# What is a "linear set"

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

I'm reading "*L'hypothèse du continu*" by Sierpinski. He mentions many times "ensembles linéaires" or "linear sets" without defining this notion. Does anyone know what the definition of a such a set is ?

Here is a translation into English of 2 propositions he gave :

"There exists a linear set whose cardinality is that of the continuum and whose image by any continuous function is of measure zero".

"There exists a linear set whose cardinality is that of the continuum and whose homeomorphic images have the same measure".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After checking some translations, I can safely say that by *ensemble linéaire* he means a subset of the continuum, i.e., of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

A set is said to be a *linear set* if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- it is empty;
- it contains single element;
- it satisfies the following condition:

> There are unique elements called "first" and "last" such that every element except the last has a unique successor, and every element except the first has a unique predecessor.

Comment: Your answer differs significantly from Brian M. Scott's. Are you sure you've paid due attention to the context in which the question arose?

Comment: According to this definition, the set $[0,1]\cup(2,3]$ would not be a linear set.

Comment: Also, real numbers do not have immediate successors.